# $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n}\cos\left(\dfrac{k\pi}{2n}\right)$ True or false

Tags: sequences-and-series

Hello mathematicians of MathSX, i would like to know the true value
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n}\cos(\dfrac{k\pi}{2n})=\dfrac{2}{\pi}$$
**Update**
I forgot says equal to $\dfrac{2}{\pi}$

Sorry for the inconvenience, please explain step by step.

Thank you.

Comment: You want to evaluate it? @Oromion

Comment: What's the true or false part?

Comment: This sum doesn't converge. Are you asking for the similar looking Riemann Sum?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I forgot say equal to $\dfrac{2}{\pi}$.

Comment: The LHS depends on $n$, but the RHS does not. Please edit to ask what you really intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sum doesn't converge as the OP writes it.

---

Assuming the OP meant to write the similar-looking Riemann Sum, we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{k}{n}\right) = \int_0^1\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{2}\right)dx = \frac{2}{\pi}$$

Answer (score 1):

Writing the given expression like this:-
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n} \cos\left(\frac{k \pi}{2n} \right)$$

Converting it into an integral.

$$\int_{0}^{1} \cos\left(\frac{x \pi}{2}\right) dx$$

$$\frac{2}{\pi} \sin\left(\frac{x \pi}{2} \right) |_{0}^{1}$$

This evaluates to $\frac{2}{\pi}$